# Vuejs tags and ajax

Tags: laravel-5, tags, vue.js

### Hello

i am coding a web page of posts, where I'd like to add a tag system, something like stack overflow.

I have found many useful codes already made like Tag it by: aehlke.
The problem it´s that i want to use almost all the code by vuejs.org.

I am at laravel 5.3 framework and vuejs also using jquery.

Coul you please help me with the js to make a "separated by comma" tag that only can use the tags already in Tags table.

i used the example in vuejs.org to make made a searchbox that searches at a vue var and displays it at the bottom, i tought i coul use laravel variables to make the vuejs var and then search, but how could i make that each time a value its clicked on the table at bottom, the text fields updates with a tag inside.

---

```
<script type="text/x-template" id="grid-template">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="
        entry in data
        | filterBy filterKey
        | orderBy sortKey sortOrders[sortKey]">
        <td v-for="key in columns">
          <a href="#">{{entry[key]}}</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</script>

<div id="demo">
  <form id="search">
    Search <input name="query" v-model="searchQuery">
  </form>
  <demo-grid
    :data="gridData"
    :columns="gridColumns"
    :filter-key="searchQuery">
  </demo-grid>
</div>
```

---

```
Vue.component('demo-grid', {
  template: '#grid-template',
  props: {
    data: Array,
    columns: Array,
    filterKey: String
  },

  methods: {
    sortBy: function (key) {
      this.sortKey = key
      this.sortOrders[key] = this.sortOrders[key] * -1
    }
  }
})

// bootstrap the demo
var demo = new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
    searchQuery: '',
    gridColumns: ['tag'],
    gridData: [
      { tag: 'Movies'},
      { tag: 'Tv Shows' },
      { tag: 'Books'},
      { tag: 'Comics' }
    ]
  }
})
```

Help.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a "code-this-for-me"-site so if you want some help you need to post some code and someone might tell you what's wrong with it.

Anyhow, one of these JS libraries might be of interest to you:

https://select2.github.io/

http://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/

Comment: Yes sorry, i just added what i have made. Anything can help, thankyou.